# CodeIgniter Query Builder bug

Tags: php, database, oracle, codeigniter, orm

I am having an issue with CodeIgniter query builder irregular behaviour and running out of ideas where is the problem.. The code:

```
    $this->db->order_by('MT_SHORT_NAME', 'ASC');
    $this->db->order_by('ORD_CREATION_DATETIME', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get_where($this->OrderViewTable, array('ORD_WORK_DATE >=' => $from, 'ORD_WORK_DATE <=' => $to));
    return $query->result_array();
```

Generates those two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM "UTC_ORDER_VIEW" WHERE "ORD_WORK_DATE" >= '2019-02-07' AND "ORD_WORK_DATE" <= '2019-02-07' ORDER BY "MT_SHORT_NAME" ASC, "ORD_CREATION_DATETIME" DESC
SELECT * FROM "UTC_ORDER_VIEW" WHERE "ORD_WORK_DATE" >= "=" '2019-02-07' AND "ORD_WORK_DATE" <= "=" '2019-02-07' ORDER BY "MT_SHORT_NAME" ASC, "ORD_CREATION_DATETIME" DESC
```

As can be seen there is additional "=" in second query, which happens irregulary. Please, help

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Also, use the proper date format that will match your input and value in DB

```
$this->db->order_by('MT_SHORT_NAME', 'ASC');
$this->db->order_by('ORD_CREATION_DATETIME', 'DESC');
$this->db->where('ORD_WORK_DATE >=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($first_date));
$this->db->where('ORD_WORK_DATE <=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($second_date));
return $this->db->get($this->OrderViewTable)->result_array();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->db->where('ORD_WORK_DATE >=', $first_date);
$this->db->where('ORD_WORK_DATE <=', $second_date);
return $this->db->get($this->OrderViewTable)->result_array();
```

Comment: Could you explain logic behind it? What does it change?